# C# Потоки. Ввод данных и не корректное отображение

Tags: c#, асинхронность

Создал второй поток для отображения нажатой клавиши НО Первая обработка происходит с Main потока, а со второго никакой информации, и только после второго нажатия выводит уже со второго потока а с Main не обрабатывает.
Будто синхронно работает Сначала в мейн потом в другом. Как фиксить?

```
    using System;
    using System.Threading;
    //using System.Timers;

    namespace ConsoleSnake
    {
        public class Params
        {
            int x;
            int y;
            public Params(int x,int y)
            {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
            }
            public int GetX()
            {
                return this.x;
            }

            public int GetY()
            {
                return this.y;
            }
        }
        class Program
        {
            public static void keylogger() //Функция в потоке . Второй клик обработка тут
            {
                ConsoleKeyInfo keyinfoo;
                do
                {
                    keyinfoo = Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.WriteLine(keyinfoo.Key + " was pressed");
                }
                while (keyinfoo.Key != ConsoleKey.X);
            }
            public static void timerexec(object tets)
            {
                Params p = tets as Params;
                int X = p.GetX(); 
                int Y = p.GetY();

                Console.Clear();

                for (int f = 0; Y > f; f++)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; X > i; i++)
                    {
                        Console.Write("0");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }

            }
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Thread kl = new Thread(keylogger);
                kl.Start(); //Поток с кейлогером
                kl.IsBackground = false;
                TimerCallback tc = new TimerCallback(timerexec); 
                Params pa = new Params(50, 20);
                Timer ti = new Timer(tc,pa,0,1000);
                ConsoleKeyInfo keyinfo = new ConsoleKeyInfo();
                do
                {
                    keyinfo = Console.ReadKey();
                }
                while (keyinfo.Key != ConsoleKey.X); //Первый клик обработка тут

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Один из методов `ReadKey` читает значение из консоли и второму ничего не остаётся. Какой именно успеет прочитать первым - дело случая. Как фиксить - не читайте ввод в разных потоках.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov судя по исходникам, там еще, вроде, много блоков синхронизации... => параллельная работа вообще лишена смысла...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov А если нужно считать в обеих потоках и уже независимо сделать 2 разных действия которые не должны быть синхронными